# Bash shell snippet to check if mounted Samba share is not busy

Tags: bash, samba, mount, cifs

```
#!/bin/sh

mount -t cifs //192.168.5.90/share -o password='' /mnt/tera_nas

rsync -av --super --delete --recursive /home/ /mnt/tera_nas/home/

# sleep 5m (i want to avoid using this)

# Bash shell snippet to check if mounted Samba share is not busy before issuing umount command

umount /mnt/tera_nas/
```

Comment: Are you asking for us to write the "Bash shell snippet to check if mounted Samba share is not busy before issuing umount command" portion of that script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just lazy unmount it, using the -l flag. This will remove the mount point from the filesystem (so no new operations can start), and will finish the proper unmount once it is no longer busy.

Comment: As per http://serverfault.com/users/1293/dennis-williamson:

umount -l /mnt/tera_nas

Did the trick for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you could lsof to see if it has any open file descriptors

Comment: Agreed. I'd do lsof -n | grep mountpoint

Answer (score 3):

you could use "fuser -m mountpoint" to see if anyone is accessing the path.

Answer (score 2):

Let umount do the work for you:

```
while ! $(umount /mnt/tera_nas/ 2>/dev/null)
do
    echo "not yet"
    sleep 5m
done
echo "now it is"
```

You could shorten the sleep time, but I wouldn't eliminate it. It serves a different role here than in your question.

Answer (score 1):

2[Dennis Williamson](https://serverfault.com/users/1293/dennis-williamson):

I'd rather use

```
umount -l /mnt/tera_nas
```

at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use `automount` to do this for you automatically, the mountpoint `/mnt/tera_nas/home/` will be mounted automatically when it is accessed, then unmounted once it is no longer needed.

```
# /etc/auto.master
/mnt auto.mnt

# /etc/auto.mnt
tera_nas -t cifs,password='' ://192.168.5.90/share
```

Then `service autofs restart`